# How to reference multiple dataframe columns to calculate a new column of weighted averages in R

Tags: r, dataframe, weighted, weighted-average

I am currently calculating the weighted average column for my dataframe through manual referencing of each column name. Is there a way to shorten the code by multiplying sets of arrays
eg:
 `df[,c(A,B,C)]` and `df[,c(PerA,PerB,PerC)]` to obtain the weighted average, like the SUMPRODUCT in Excel? Especially if I have multiple input columns to calculate the weighted average column

```
df$WtAvg = df$A*dfPerA + df$B*df$PerB + df$C*df$PerC
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without transforming your dataframe and assuming that first half of the dataframe is the size and the second half is the weight, you can use `weighted.mean` function in `apply` function:

```r
df$WtAvg = apply(df,1,function(x){weighted.mean(x[1:(ncol(df)/2)],
                                                x[(ncol(df)/2+1):ncol(df)])})
```

And you get the following output:

```r
> df
  A B C PerA PerB PerC WtAvg
1 1 2 3  0.1  0.2  0.7   2.6
2 4 5 6  0.5  0.3  0.2   4.7
3 7 8 9  0.6  0.1  0.3   7.7
```